# Arduino mega with L298n and Motors with Encoders not registering encoders

Tags: arduino, robotics, encoder, arduino-c++, motordriver

I am trying to follow a tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PCuDnpgiew&list=PLunhqkrRNRhYAffV8JDiFOatQXuU-NnxT&index=9) on using ROS with Arduino to control motors, and I have connected my [L298N](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BK1QL5T) with the [battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ME3ZH7C) precisely as the video describes and have uploaded [sketch](https://github.com/joshnewans/ros_arduino_bridge) 1 with the supporting folder and it loads properly. The Arduino is powered properly via USB, but that connection is not shown in the diagram. When I type the "e" command, I get the proper response of "0 0" and when I do the "o 255 255" it says "OK" and drives properly but upon using "e" to recheck the encoders I am getting the same "0 0". If anyone can spot something wrong with this, I would really appreciate the help in fixing it. Diagram and Code Below

[image: Diagram]

Code:

```cpp
#define USE_BASE      // Enable the base controller code
//#undef USE_BASE     // Disable the base controller code

/* Define the motor controller and encoder library you are using */
#ifdef USE_BASE
   /* The Pololu VNH5019 dual motor driver shield */
   //#define POLOLU_VNH5019

   /* The Pololu MC33926 dual motor driver shield */
   //#define POLOLU_MC33926

   /* The RoboGaia encoder shield */
   //#define ROBOGAIA
   
   /* Encoders directly attached to Arduino board */
   #define ARDUINO_ENC_COUNTER

   /* L298 Motor driver*/
   #define L298_MOTOR_DRIVER
#endif

//#define USE_SERVOS  // Enable use of PWM servos as defined in servos.h
#undef USE_SERVOS     // Disable use of PWM servos

/* Serial port baud rate */
#define BAUDRATE      57600

/* Maximum PWM signal */
#define MAX_PWM        255

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif

/* Include definition of serial commands */
#include "commands.h"

/* Sensor functions */
#include "sensors.h"

/* Include servo support if required */
#ifdef USE_SERVOS
   #include <Servo.h>
   #include "servos.h"
#endif

#ifdef USE_BASE
  /* Motor driver function definitions */
  #include "motor_driver.h"

  /* Encoder driver function definitions */
  #include "encoder_driver.h"

  /* PID parameters and functions */
  #include "diff_controller.h"

  /* Run the PID loop at 30 times per second */
  #define PID_RATE           30     // Hz

  /* Convert the rate into an interval */
  const int PID_INTERVAL = 1000 / PID_RATE;
  
  /* Track the next time we make a PID calculation */
  unsigned long nextPID = PID_INTERVAL;

  /* Stop the robot if it hasn't received a movement command
   in this number of milliseconds */
  #define AUTO_STOP_INTERVAL 2000
  long lastMotorCommand = AUTO_STOP_INTERVAL;
#endif

/* Variable initialization */

// A pair of varibles to help parse serial commands (thanks Fergs)
int arg = 0;
int index = 0;

// Variable to hold an input character
char chr;

// Variable to hold the current single-character command
char cmd;

// Character arrays to hold the first and second arguments
char argv1[16];
char argv2[16];

// The arguments converted to integers
long arg1;
long arg2;

/* Clear the current command parameters */
void resetCommand() {
  cmd = NULL;
  memset(argv1, 0, sizeof(argv1));
  memset(argv2, 0, sizeof(argv2));
  arg1 = 0;
  arg2 = 0;
  arg = 0;
  index = 0;
}

/* Run a command.  Commands are defined in commands.h */
int runCommand() {
  int i = 0;
  char *p = argv1;
  char *str;
  int pid_args[4];
  arg1 = atoi(argv1);
  arg2 = atoi(argv2);
  
  switch(cmd) {
  case GET_BAUDRATE:
    Serial.println(BAUDRATE);
    break;
  case ANALOG_READ:
    Serial.println(analogRead(arg1));
    break;
  case DIGITAL_READ:
    Serial.println(digitalRead(arg1));
    break;
  case ANALOG_WRITE:
    analogWrite(arg1, arg2);
    Serial.println("OK"); 
    break;
  case DIGITAL_WRITE:
    if (arg2 == 0) digitalWrite(arg1, LOW);
    else if (arg2 == 1) digitalWrite(arg1, HIGH);
    Serial.println("OK"); 
    break;
  case PIN_MODE:
    if (arg2 == 0) pinMode(arg1, INPUT);
    else if (arg2 == 1) pinMode(arg1, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println("OK");
    break;
  case PING:
    Serial.println(Ping(arg1));
    break;
#ifdef USE_SERVOS
  case SERVO_WRITE:
    servos[arg1].setTargetPosition(arg2);
    Serial.println("OK");
    break;
  case SERVO_READ:
    Serial.println(servos[arg1].getServo().read());
    break;
#endif
    
#ifdef USE_BASE
  case READ_ENCODERS:
    Serial.print(readEncoder(LEFT));
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(readEncoder(RIGHT));
    break;
   case RESET_ENCODERS:
    resetEncoders();
    resetPID();
    Serial.println("OK");
    break;
  case MOTOR_SPEEDS:
    /* Reset the auto stop timer */
    lastMotorCommand = millis();
    if (arg1 == 0 && arg2 == 0) {
      setMotorSpeeds(0, 0);
      resetPID();
      moving = 0;
    }
    else moving = 1;
    leftPID.TargetTicksPerFrame = arg1;
    rightPID.TargetTicksPerFrame = arg2;
    Serial.println("OK"); 
    break;
  case MOTOR_RAW_PWM:
    /* Reset the auto stop timer */
    lastMotorCommand = millis();
    resetPID();
    moving = 0; // Sneaky way to temporarily disable the PID
    setMotorSpeeds(arg1, arg2);
    Serial.println("OK"); 
    break;
  case UPDATE_PID:
    while ((str = strtok_r(p, ":", &p)) != '\0') {
       pid_args[i] = atoi(str);
       i++;
    }
    Kp = pid_args[0];
    Kd = pid_args[1];
    Ki = pid_args[2];
    Ko = pid_args[3];
    Serial.println("OK");
    break;
#endif
  default:
    Serial.println("Invalid Command");
    break;
  }
}

/* Setup function--runs once at startup. */
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUDRATE);

// Initialize the motor controller if used */
#ifdef USE_BASE
  #ifdef ARDUINO_ENC_COUNTER
    //set as inputs
    DDRD &= ~(1<<LEFT_ENC_PIN_A);
    DDRD &= ~(1<<LEFT_ENC_PIN_B);
    DDRC &= ~(1<<RIGHT_ENC_PIN_A);
    DDRC &= ~(1<<RIGHT_ENC_PIN_B);
    
    //enable pull up resistors
    PORTD |= (1<<LEFT_ENC_PIN_A);
    PORTD |= (1<<LEFT_ENC_PIN_B);
    PORTC |= (1<<RIGHT_ENC_PIN_A);
    PORTC |= (1<<RIGHT_ENC_PIN_B);
    
    // tell pin change mask to listen to left encoder pins
    PCMSK2 |= (1 << LEFT_ENC_PIN_A)|(1 << LEFT_ENC_PIN_B);
    // tell pin change mask to listen to right encoder pins
    PCMSK1 |= (1 << RIGHT_ENC_PIN_A)|(1 << RIGHT_ENC_PIN_B);
    
    // enable PCINT1 and PCINT2 interrupt in the general interrupt mask
    PCICR |= (1 << PCIE1) | (1 << PCIE2);
  #endif
  initMotorController();
  resetPID();
#endif

/* Attach servos if used */
  #ifdef USE_SERVOS
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N_SERVOS; i++) {
      servos[i].initServo(
          servoPins[i],
          stepDelay[i],
          servoInitPosition[i]);
    }
  #endif
}

/* Enter the main loop.  Read and parse input from the serial port
   and run any valid commands. Run a PID calculation at the target
   interval and check for auto-stop conditions.
*/
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    
    // Read the next character
    chr = Serial.read();

    // Terminate a command with a CR
    if (chr == 13) {
      if (arg == 1) argv1[index] = NULL;
      else if (arg == 2) argv2[index] = NULL;
      runCommand();
      resetCommand();
    }
    // Use spaces to delimit parts of the command
    else if (chr == ' ') {
      // Step through the arguments
      if (arg == 0) arg = 1;
      else if (arg == 1)  {
        argv1[index] = NULL;
        arg = 2;
        index = 0;
      }
      continue;
    }
    else {
      if (arg == 0) {
        // The first arg is the single-letter command
        cmd = chr;
      }
      else if (arg == 1) {
        // Subsequent arguments can be more than one character
        argv1[index] = chr;
        index++;
      }
      else if (arg == 2) {
        argv2[index] = chr;
        index++;
      }
    }
  }
  
// If we are using base control, run a PID calculation at the appropriate intervals
#ifdef USE_BASE
  if (millis() > nextPID) {
    updatePID();
    nextPID += PID_INTERVAL;
  }
  
  // Check to see if we have exceeded the auto-stop interval
  if ((millis() - lastMotorCommand) > AUTO_STOP_INTERVAL) {;
    setMotorSpeeds(0, 0);
    moving = 0;
  }
#endif

// Sweep servos
#ifdef USE_SERVOS
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < N_SERVOS; i++) {
    servos[i].doSweep();
  }
#endif
}
```

Encoder Pin Designations:

```cpp
/* *************************************************************
   Encoder driver function definitions - by James Nugen
   ************************************************************ */
   
   
#ifdef ARDUINO_ENC_COUNTER
  //below can be changed, but should be PORTD pins; 
  //otherwise additional changes in the code are required
  #define LEFT_ENC_PIN_A PD2  //pin 2
  #define LEFT_ENC_PIN_B PD3  //pin 3
  
  //below can be changed, but should be PORTC pins
  #define RIGHT_ENC_PIN_A PC4  //pin A4
  #define RIGHT_ENC_PIN_B PC5   //pin A5
#endif
   
long readEncoder(int i);
void resetEncoder(int i);
void resetEncoders();
```

Encoder Driver:

```cpp
/* *************************************************************
   Encoder definitions
   
   Add an "#ifdef" block to this file to include support for
   a particular encoder board or library. Then add the appropriate
   #define near the top of the main ROSArduinoBridge.ino file.
   
   ************************************************************ */
   
#ifdef USE_BASE

#ifdef ROBOGAIA
  /* The Robogaia Mega Encoder shield */
  #include "MegaEncoderCounter.h"

  /* Create the encoder shield object */
  MegaEncoderCounter encoders = MegaEncoderCounter(4); // Initializes the Mega Encoder Counter in the 4X Count mode
  
  /* Wrap the encoder reading function */
  long readEncoder(int i) {
    if (i == LEFT) return encoders.YAxisGetCount();
    else return encoders.XAxisGetCount();
  }

  /* Wrap the encoder reset function */
  void resetEncoder(int i) {
    if (i == LEFT) return encoders.YAxisReset();
    else return encoders.XAxisReset();
  }
#elif defined(ARDUINO_ENC_COUNTER)
  volatile long left_enc_pos = 0L;
  volatile long right_enc_pos = 0L;
  static const int8_t ENC_STATES [] = {0,1,-1,0,-1,0,0,1,1,0,0,-1,0,-1,1,0};  //encoder lookup table
    
  /* Interrupt routine for LEFT encoder, taking care of actual counting */
  ISR (PCINT2_vect){
    static uint8_t enc_last=0;
        
    enc_last <<=2; //shift previous state two places
    enc_last |= (PIND & (3 << 2)) >> 2; //read the current state into lowest 2 bits
  
    left_enc_pos += ENC_STATES[(enc_last & 0x0f)];
  }
  
  /* Interrupt routine for RIGHT encoder, taking care of actual counting */
  ISR (PCINT1_vect){
        static uint8_t enc_last=0;
            
    enc_last <<=2; //shift previous state two places
    enc_last |= (PINC & (3 << 4)) >> 4; //read the current state into lowest 2 bits
  
    right_enc_pos += ENC_STATES[(enc_last & 0x0f)];
  }
  
  /* Wrap the encoder reading function */
  long readEncoder(int i) {
    if (i == LEFT) return left_enc_pos;
    else return right_enc_pos;
  }

  /* Wrap the encoder reset function */
  void resetEncoder(int i) {
    if (i == LEFT){
      left_enc_pos=0L;
      return;
    } else { 
      right_enc_pos=0L;
      return;
    }
  }
#else
  #error A encoder driver must be selected!
#endif

/* Wrap the encoder reset function */
void resetEncoders() {
  resetEncoder(LEFT);
  resetEncoder(RIGHT);
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use a Mega instead of an Uno, the pin ports are different.

So change the port from PD4 to PE4 and PD3 to PE5. Also, change PC4 to PF4 and PC5 to PF5.

In the `Encoder.ino`, you also have to change the ports accordingly.

`Encoder.h`:

```
  #define LEFT_ENC_PIN_A PE4  //pin 2
  #define LEFT_ENC_PIN_B PE5  //pin 3
  
  //below can be changed, but should be PORTC pins
  #define RIGHT_ENC_PIN_A PF5  //pin A4
  #define RIGHT_ENC_PIN_B PF5   //pin A5
```

`Encoder.ino`:

```
  /* Interrupt routine for LEFT encoder, taking care of actual counting */
  ISR (PCINT2_vect){
    static uint8_t enc_last=0;
        
    enc_last <<=2; //shift previous state two places
    enc_last |= (PINE & (3 << 2)) >> 2; //read the current state into lowest 2 bits
  
    left_enc_pos += ENC_STATES[(enc_last & 0x0f)];
  }
  
  /* Interrupt routine for RIGHT encoder, taking care of actual counting */
  ISR (PCINT1_vect){
        static uint8_t enc_last=0;
            
    enc_last <<=2; //shift previous state two places
    enc_last |= (PINF & (3 << 4)) >> 4; //read the current state into lowest 2 bits
  
    right_enc_pos += ENC_STATES[(enc_last & 0x0f)];
  }
```